# JNLP Error parsing or reading file

Tags: java, file, jnlp, java-web-start

I have a jnlp file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="file:///homes/rm3710/SelfAssessment" href="selfAssessment.jnlp">
    <information>
        <title>Dynamic Tree Demo</title>

        <offline-allowed/>
    </information>
    <resources>
        <!-- Application Resources -->
        <j2se version="1.6+" href=
           "http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
        <jar href="test.jar"
            main="true" />

    </resources>
    <application-desc
         name="Dynamic Tree Demo Application"
         main-class="logic.MyApplication"
         width="300"
         height="300">
     </application-desc>
     <update check="background"/>
</jnlp>
```

I have placed this file, the html file and my test.jar which contains my swing application into one folder. I am trying to use Java WebStart. When i click on the launch button the following error message comes up as

```
net.sourceforge.jnlp.LaunchException: Fatal: Read Error: Could not
read or parse the JNLP file.    at
net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.fromUrl(Launcher.java:491)    at
net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:283)     at
net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.Boot.run(Boot.java:202)    at
net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.Boot.run(Boot.java:51)     at
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  at
net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.Boot.main(Boot.java:168) Caused by:
java.io.IOException: /homes/rm3710/SelfAssessment/Untitled Document
1/selfAssessment.jnlp (Not a directory)     at
net.sourceforge.jnlp.JNLPFile.openURL(JNLPFile.java:282)    at
net.sourceforge.jnlp.JNLPFile.<init>(JNLPFile.java:212)     at
net.sourceforge.jnlp.JNLPFile.<init>(JNLPFile.java:188)     at
net.sourceforge.jnlp.JNLPFile.<init>(JNLPFile.java:173)     at
net.sourceforge.jnlp.JNLPFile.<init>(JNLPFile.java:159)     at
net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.fromUrl(Launcher.java:477)    ... 5 more
Caused by:  java.io.IOException: /homes/rm3710/SelfAssessment/Untitled
Document 1/selfAssessment.jnlp (Not a directory)    at
net.sourceforge.jnlp.JNLPFile.openURL(JNLPFile.java:282)    at
net.sourceforge.jnlp.JNLPFile.<init>(JNLPFile.java:212)     at
net.sourceforge.jnlp.JNLPFile.<init>(JNLPFile.java:188)     at
net.sourceforge.jnlp.JNLPFile.<init>(JNLPFile.java:173)     at
net.sourceforge.jnlp.JNLPFile.<init>(JNLPFile.java:159)     at
net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.fromUrl(Launcher.java:477)    at
net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:283)     at
net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.Boot.run(Boot.java:202)    at
net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.Boot.run(Boot.java:51)     at
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  at
net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.Boot.main(Boot.java:168)
```

Comment: How does `Untitled Document 1` come into the path?  Do you have a directory of that name on the file system?  Was it ever mentioned in the JNLP?  BTW - that JNLP appears invalid to me.  Be sure to check it using [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/).

Comment: Untitled Document 1 is the html file that i use to call the jnlp from.If you would please explain as to what is invalid in the jnlp. i have no experience with this, and am working on  jnlp the first time please help/

Comment: *"If you would please explain as to what is invalid in the jnlp."*  No.  I programmed JaNeLA and offer it free so you can check the file using it.  It is better at checking files than I am, and if you do not understand the error messages, you can (1st check the help page), then ask on an 'xml-validation' question. *"Untitled Document 1 is the html file"*  Huh?  That seems definitely screwed up.  There is no way the name of the HTML from which the JNLP is linked **should** end as part of the code base.  But let me check, is it called `Untitled Document 1` or `Untitled Document 1.html` or..?

Comment: hi, it is called Untitled Document 1 and it is saved an a html type page. it is placed in the same directory as the jnlp file and the jar file for my program. i have downloaded the janela jar. I am unable to use it. please help me how to use it

Comment: please help me in correcting the jnlp file.

Comment: *"please help me how to use it"*  See [JaNeLA help page 1](http://pscode.org/janela/) & [page 2](http://pscode.org/janela/help.html).  Note that I am almost at the point of abandoning you to solve this on your own (or with help from the 1 or 2 other people here with the expertise to help solve it).  I find your vague comments quite pathetic, e.g. *"I am unable to use it"* explain why.  What happened when you tried to use it?  What did you expect to happen?  Another e.g. *"..it is called Untitled Document 1 and it is saved an a html type page"*  **Copy/paste the *file name!***

Comment: I have created a new directory with only the jnlp file and the test.jar and now when i try to launch the jnlp i get this error net.sourceforge.jnlp.LaunchException: Fatal: Launch Error: Could not launch JNLP file. 
Caused by:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: logic.MyApplication at

Comment: Hi, i have checked the jnlp file qith janela. it does not seem to have an error. I went throught the check tables. however i still get the error of classNotFoundException